# Hiding the column label "Values" in pivot table using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

How does one hide the column label "**Values**" in pivot table using VBA? I've tried to search on Google for hours but to no avail. I did try `.Visible`, `.Enable`, and `.CompactLayoutColumnHeader` then I set them to equal to `False` but it's either returning an error or unable to work. I can manually hide this label by right clicking then going into **PivotTable Options** ► **Display** and clearing the check box of '**Show the Values row**', but dunno how to do this using VBA.

Comment: if you can do it manually, simply press "Record Macro", do it and check the code recorded code. http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html

Comment: @Vityata OMG, I forgot that feature. Thanks. Could you convert your comment to the answer so that I can upvote it?

Comment: Done :) Thank you as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTbleName").ShowValuesRow = False
```

Comment: would the brave downvoter ever kindly explain what was wrong with this answer and how to improve it?

Comment: I got the same downvote for no reason to this question even if my question seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

Comment to answer per request:

If you can do it manually, simply press "Record Macro", do it and check the code recorded code.  http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html